# how to update existing CDKMetadata Modules from cdkv1 to cdkv2?

Tags: deployment, terraform, upgrade, aws-cdk, aws-iam-policy

how to update existing CDKMetadata Modules from cdkv1 to cdkv2?

I am seeing stack failed error while deployment after migrating to cdkv2 and suspect below code block has issue. But I am not sure how to replace modules part of it. Do I still require Modules in cdkv2?

```
    Type: AWS::CDK::Metadata
    Properties:
      Modules: aws-cdk=1.16.3,@aws-cdk/aws-iam=1.16.3,@aws-cdk/core=1.16.3,@aws-cdk/cx-api=1.16.3,@aws-cdk/region-info=1.16.3,jsii-runtime=node.js/v19.1.0
```

Please guide. Let me know in case more information required.

Comment: No, this is not the issue. Metadata is updated automatically, you don't have to do anything extra. You'll need to add details about your error.